# How to close Form1 and open Form2

Tags: c#

In Form1 when progressbar is completed then in timer_tick events' else part the following code is written by me:

```
frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
login.Show();
timer1.Enabled = false;
this.Hide();
```

So any solution to close the `Form1` instead of the hide `Form1`?

Comment: The problem here is, that the `Form1` is the `MainForm` and if you close that, the Application terminates.

Comment: shouldn't that be `frmLogin.Show()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have something called the [`ApplicationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

Use it like this:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ApplicationContext();

FormX formX = new FormX(applicationContext);
applicationContext.MainForm = formX;

Application.Run(applicationContext);
```

When closing `Form1`, hand over the `MainForm`

```
FormY formY = new FormY(applicationContext);
applicationContext.MainForm = formY;
```

Another option is to make a static `ApplicationContext`. That wouldn't require passing it around.

Comment: I cannot understand this code. Please any other way to remove this problem.

Comment: Actually I do not understand whole code. where to write the first code part and second two line code are in which location or event write.

Comment: @argciv: The first part is placed in Program.cs (instead of the Application.Run(form); call. The second part is at your event where you open the second form. Try the example at MSDN.

Comment: frmSplash formX = new frmSplash(applicationContext);                 In the above line i have an error                                    new frmSplash(applicationContext); in this code red line

Comment: You should create a constructor having the parameter applicationContext. You save this in your form and use it when you hand over the MainForm property to another form.

Comment: error is the as following : 
'Courier_Management_System.frmSlash does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Add a constructor frmSlash(ApplicationContext context)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it from the main form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        var login=new LoginForm();
        if(login.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Validation ok
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So before the main form shows up, it loads and shows the `LoginForm`. When that is done, it closes the `LoginForm` and shows the main form.

Comment: This code is not working. Please you have any other better solution then give that code.

Comment: I tied the code before posting and it produced the desired effect. How is this not working? Can you elaborate.