# When Form1 loads, hide it and show Form2

Tags: c#, forms, hide

Been stuck for quite a while reading similar posts here, I did find a solution but it was in dummy code and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have 2 forms, when the main form loads up I want to hide it and show form2 (the login form)

code looks like this.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    login loginform = new login();
    loginform.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

But when I run the program both forms are open and visible.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the main form be hidden?

Answer (score 1):

The `Hide` method does not have any effect from the `Load` event, since there isn't a handle created yet.

You have two options:

- Using the `Shown` event (or better, the `HandleCreated` event) and hide it if a condition is met (like a variable 'logon form not shown')
- Show the logon form as start form, then open the 'main' form. You can do this by [passing an `ApplicationContext` around and pass on control to the main form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973068/993547).

Comment: Alternatively you could add a handler to the `HandleCreated` event.

Comment: Yes, that is a better one. @BarryO'Kane Didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help of owner property, here is working example

**Main form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loginFormMax = new LoginFormMax { Owner = this };//save main form as owner inside child form
        loginFormMax.Show();
    }
}
```

**Child Form**

```
public partial class LoginFormMax : Form
{
    public LoginFormMax()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoginFormMax_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var owner = this.Owner;
        owner.Hide();//now you have control over owner form, just hide it
    }

    private void LoginFormMax_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        var owner = this.Owner;
        owner.Show();//now you have control over owner form, just show it again
    }
}
```